# Key error when trying to fill nan values of a extremely large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kaggle

```
# Making use of the GPU library. This only works for integer only features at present.
def read_file_int(path = '', usecols = None):
    # LOAD DATAFRAME
    if usecols is not None: df = cudf.read_feather(path, columns=usecols)
    else: df = cudf.read_feather(path)
    # REDUCE DTYPE FOR CUSTOMER AND DATE
#   df['customer_ID'] = df['customer_ID'].str[-16:].str.hex_to_int().astype('int64')
    df.S_2 = cudf.to_datetime(df.S_2)
    # CREATE OVERALL ROW MISS VALUE
    features = [x for x in df.columns.values if x not in ['customer_ID', 'target']]
    df['n_missing'] = df[features].isna().sum(axis=1)
    # FILL NAN
    #df = df.fillna(NAN_VALUE) 
    # KEEP ONLY FINAL CUSTOMER ID UNTIL FUTURE TIME SERIES WORK BEGINS
    df_out = df.groupby(['customer_ID']).tail(1).reset_index(drop=True)
    print('shape of data:', df_out.shape)
    del df
    return df_out

# To ensure that the categorical features are imported only using CPU
def read_file_cpu(path = '', usecols = None):
    # LOAD DATAFRAME
    if usecols is not None: df = pd.read_feather(path, columns=usecols)
    else: df = pd.read_feather(path)
    # REDUCE DTYPE FOR CUSTOMER AND DATE
#   df['customer_ID'] = df['customer_ID'].str[-16:].str.hex_to_int().astype('int64')
    df.S_2 = pd.to_datetime(df.S_2)
    # CREATE OVERALL ROW MISS VALUE
    features = [x for x in df.columns.values if x not in ['customer_ID', 'target']]
    df['n_missing'] = df[features].isna().sum(axis=1)
    # FILL NAN
     
    features_num = [x for x in df._get_numeric_data().columns.values if x not in ['customer_ID', 'target']]
    df = df[features_num].fillna(NAN_VALUE) 
    # KEEP ONLY FINAL CUSTOMER ID UNTIL FUTURE TIME SERIES WORK BEGINS
    df_out = df.groupby(['customer_ID']).tail(1).reset_index(drop=True)
    print('shape of data:', df_out.shape)
    del df
    return df_out

print('Reading train data...')
TRAIN_PATH = '../input/amexfeather/train_data.ftr'
train_df = read_file_cpu(path = TRAIN_PATH)

print('Reading test data...')
TEST_PATH = '../input/amexfeather/test_data.ftr'
test_df = read_file_cpu(path = TEST_PATH)
```

**The dataset of this competition has a considerable size. If you read the original csv files, the data barely fits into memory. That's why we read the data from @munumbutt's AMEX-Feather-Dataset. In this Feather file, the floating point precision has been reduced from 64 bit to 16 bit. And reading a Feather file is faster than reading a csv file because the Feather file format is binary.

There are 5.5 million rows for training and 11 million rows of test data.But it returns the below error.Here is my notebook
[https://www.kaggle.com/code/mcc117/american-express-default-prediction](https://kaggle.com/code/mcc117/american-express-default-prediction)**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_24/299065218.py in <module>
     41 print('Reading train data...')
     42 TRAIN_PATH = '../input/amexfeather/train_data.ftr'
---> 43 train_df = read_file_cpu(path = TRAIN_PATH)
     44 
     45 print('Reading test data...')

/tmp/ipykernel_24/299065218.py in read_file_cpu(path, usecols)
     34     df = df[features_num].fillna(NAN_VALUE)
     35     # KEEP ONLY FINAL CUSTOMER ID UNTIL FUTURE TIME SERIES WORK BEGINS
---> 36     df_out = df.groupby(['customer_ID']).tail(1).reset_index(drop=True)
     37     print('shape of data:', df_out.shape)
     38     del df

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, dropna)
   7639             squeeze=squeeze,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
   7640             observed=observed,
-> 7641             dropna=dropna,
   7642         )
   7643 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in __init__(self, obj, keys, axis, level, grouper, exclusions, selection, as_index, sort, group_keys, squeeze, observed, mutated, dropna)
    895                 observed=observed,
    896                 mutated=self.mutated,
--> 897                 dropna=self.dropna,
    898             )
    899 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py in get_grouper(obj, key, axis, level, sort, observed, mutated, validate, dropna)
    860                 in_axis, level, gpr = False, gpr, None
    861             else:
--> 862                 raise KeyError(gpr)
    863         elif isinstance(gpr, Grouper) and gpr.key is not None:
    864             # Add key to exclusions

KeyError: 'customer_ID'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like there's a problem with the `customer_ID` column. Could you share a sample of the dataset?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/code/mcc117/american-express-default-prediction

Answer (score 0):

In this line you remove `customer_ID` from the dataframe.

```
features_num = [x for x in df._get_numeric_data().columns.values if x not in ['customer_ID', 'target']]
df = df[features_num].fillna(NAN_VALUE)
```

And then in the next line you try to use `customer_ID`.

```
df_out = df.groupby(['customer_ID']).tail(1).reset_index(drop=True)
```